# error compiling the linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I was trying to compile the linux kernel, but getting some errors.
While running the top Makefile i am getting the following errors :-

```
CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
  SYMLINK include/asm -> include/asm-x86
  HOSTCC  scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp
scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp.c:32:19: error: flask.h: No such file or directory
scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp.c:56:29: error: class_to_string.h: No such file or directory
scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp.c:61:35: error: initial_sid_to_string.h: No such file or directory
scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp.c:66:35: error: common_perm_to_string.h: No such file or directory
scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp.c:91:24: error: av_inherit.h: No such file or directory
scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp.c:95:28: error: av_permissions.h: No such file or directory
scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp.c:103:31: error: av_perm_to_string.h: No such file or directory
scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp.c: In function â€˜mainâ€™:
scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp.c:140: error: â€˜initial_sid_to_stringâ€™ undeclared (first use in this function)
scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp.c:140: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp.c:140: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[3]: *** [scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/selinux/mdp] Error 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/selinux] Error 2
make: *** [scripts] Error 2
```

Prior to build i configured the using 
make oldconfig

seems that the files in error log were supposed to be generated during configuration.
But somehow they are not getting generated and hence the error.
Searched the net but still not able to fix the errors.
I am very new to kernel programming. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing some includes for the SELinux functionality.  Make sure you've got the appropriate selinux dev packages installed.  On Ubuntu, I'm guessing what you need is libselinux1-dev.

Comment: Thank you Paul for your quick response.

can you please tell the equivalent of "libselinux1-dev" for fedora core if it happens to be something different.
From where can i get the package and where in the kernel source tree do i need to keep it??

Thanks a lot .

Comment: Generally, you just install the package and let "make" find it.  I don't know what it is, but since this appears to be something that selinux needs, I'd start searching in that general area.